# How to split a list or a vector in r?

Tags: r, split, sentiment-analysis

In developing of Sentiment Analysis application using R, I need to split result of the matched words,

**First** (done)

```
pos.matches = match(words, pos.words)
```

**Second** (done)

```
words_matched=words[pos.matches]
```

From the secondary step, let's take an example that the method will return

```
happy happy sad
```

My question is, how to split the result from secondary step into like this:

```
[1] happy

[2] happy 

[3] sad
```

Right now I'm using strsplit function

```
 strsplit((words[pos.matches])," ")
```

but it is notifying me that there's an error

> Warning: Error in cat: argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by
>   'cat'

Comment: I'm not sure if this an error or a warning (as they both present here for some reason) but I'm pretty sure you are hiding some code here. `strsplit` doesn't use the `cat` function. Did you wrap this up into the `write` function or such?

Comment: can you show the output of `words[pos.matches]`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg the secondary step given me some kind a list but not in string (i think), so when i try to strsplit it gave me those error, is it any solution?

Comment: @cccmir the result from words[pos.matches] is happy happy sad (example) but it is not in string formatted

Comment: @hope9 what's the `class(words[pos.matches])`?

Comment: @ZheyuanLi i did it your way, but it give me error Error in [[: subscript out of bounds

Comment: @cccmir no class, words_matched is just variable, words_matched=words[pos.matches]

Comment: @ZheyuanLi okey, i've edited my code by using your guidance, 

 words_clean1=dput(words[pos.matches])
strsplit((words_clean1)," ")[[1]] 

it still give me error Error in [[: subscript out of bounds

Comment: @hope9 what ZheyuanLi meant is write in your r console `dput(words[pos.matches])`  and put the results in your post so we all can use it to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
words_matched = "happy happy sad"
strsplit(words_matched, " ")
```

Gives:

```
[[1]]
[1] "happy" "happy" "sad"
```

Notice the [[1]] then the [1]. What you have here is a single-element *list*, with a three-element character vector inside. If you try to cat it:

```
cat(strsplit(words_matched, " "))
```

you get the error you saw, "argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'"

You want either of these:

```
strsplit(words_matched, " ")[[1]]
unlist(strsplit(words_matched, " "))
```

They return just a 3-element character vector, which can be cat-ed.

As an aside, the [1] [2] [3] output you showed is not how either print() or cat() will format its output. I'm wondering if you actually wanted a `list`, not a character vector. If so, you have to jump through one more hoop:

as.list( unlist(strsplit(words_matched, " ")) )

Which, when `print()`-ed, gives:

```
[[1]]
[1] "happy"

[[2]]
[1] "happy"

[[3]]
[1] "sad"
```